# Styling the stroke of a geometry with a canvaspattern

Tags: openlayers

I would like to style the stroke of a polygon in a way like this:
[image: Polygon with pattern styled stroke]

The repeating image in png format looks like this:  [image: symbol]

I have tried:

1)  Create a CanvasPattern of the image (this is the symbol in png format).

2)  Assign the pattern to the color of ol.style.Stroke.

Step 1 went well.

But step 2 is not working, since the color attribute of ol.style.Stroke should  be of type ol.Color, despite the documentation of Openlayers where the color of ol.style.Stroke could also be ol.ColorLike, which means that also CanvasPattern should be allowed.

Maybe someone knows another way to accomplish the same thing?

By the way, I can fill the polygon by assigning the created CanvasPattern of the symbol, to the color of ol.style.Fill. However, in this way I am filling the polygon with the symbol; I just want the stroke to have a pattern. The "strange" thing here is, is that the attribute color of ol.style.Fill is of the same type as ol.style.Stoke, according the documentation. Anyway, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A pattern can be used as stoke color as well.

```js
// Create pattern on image load
var image = new Image();
image.onload = function() {
  var ctx = document.createElement('canvas').getContext("2d");
  var pattern = ctx.createPattern(image,"repeat");
  // create style with the pattern
  var style = new ol.style.Style({
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
      width: 8,
      color: pattern
    })
  });
  // use it on vector layer
  vector.setStyle(style);
};
// Load image
image.src = 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAA4AAAAOCAMAAAAolt3jAAAAGFBMVEUAAACPjwCmpgCbmwCCggD+/gCXlwD//wDWAMTYAAAAB3RSTlOAsr64rP62hR4cWgAAADpJREFUCNetzTEOACAIA8ACYv//YwVJxF0mLm0AJAUxtjeCPq6IkvKwNYM9c/ko1AdLTLxNtEyZbFcWKysC1htDphIAAAAASUVORK5CYII='
```

See example: https://codepen.io/viglino/pen/erErXb

Comment: Thanks. I used a typescript definition file for Openlayers. According to this file, a canvas pattern is not accepted as valid color type. However you are right, Openlayers  does accept canvas patterns, so the delivered typescript definition file was incorrect. You have answered my question, though I will raise another question because the result will not be something I want, which is shown in the picture above; the point image should be rotated according the slope of the polygon outline.

Comment: If you're looking at drawing hash lines along polygons, you should look at this example: http://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/examples/style/map.style.hashlines.html